# Access Spark Dataframe field with a Map Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My current schema is as follows

```
root
|-- product: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- Items: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
|    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
```

I will first check if any element in the *product* would be a key in Items, then check the *_2* field in the value of that entry to see if it is smaller than some value. 
My code is as follows:

```
def has(product:Seq[String],items:Map[String,(String,Long,Long)]):Double={
var count = 0
for(x<- asin)
{
    if(items.contains(x))
    {
        val item = items.get(x)
        val iitem = item.get
        val(a,b,c) = iitem
        if(b<=rank)
        {
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
}
return count.toDouble
}

def hasId = udf((product:Seq[String] ,items:Map[String,(String,Long,Long)])

=>has(product,items)/items.size.toDouble
)

for(rank <- 0 to 47)
{
    joined =joined.withColumn("hasId"+rank,hasId(col("product"),col("items")))
}
```

I am getting errors saying that

```
GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple3
```

The error appears to be something related to

```
val(a,b,c) = iitem
    if(b<=rank)
```

But I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a `MapType` or `ArrayType` column as a UDF's input, **tuple values/keys are actually passed as `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`s**. You'll have to modify your UDF to expect a `Map[String, Row]` as its second argument, and "convert" these `Row` values into tuples using pattern matching:

```
def hasId = udf((product: Seq[String], items: Map[String, Row]) =>
  has(product, items.mapValues {
    case Row(s: String, i1: Long, i2: Long) => (s, i1, i2)
  }) / items.size.toDouble
)
```

**NOTE**: somewhat unrelated to the question, looks like there's some other mistakes in the code - I assume `rank` should be passed as a parameter into `has`? And everything could be made more idiomatic by removing usages of mutable `var`s - altogether, I'm partly *guessing* this does what you need:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

def has(products: Seq[String], items: Map[String, (String, Long, Long)], rank: Long): Double = products
  .flatMap(items.get)
  .map(_._2)
  .count(_ <= rank)
  .toDouble

def hasId(rank: Long) = udf((product: Seq[String], items: Map[String, Row]) => {
  val convertedItems = items.mapValues {
    case Row(s: String, i1: Long, i2: Long) => (s, i1, i2)
  }
  has(product, convertedItems, rank) / items.size.toDouble
})

val result = (0 to 47).foldLeft(joined) {
  (df, rank) => df.withColumn("hasId" + rank, hasId(rank)(col("product"), col("items")))
}
```